# To update mercurial version in TortoiseHg I need to reinstall TortoiseHg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm a beginner with TortoiseHg/Mercurial and I'm using a previous version of TortoiseHg, this means a previous version of Mercurial too.

I need to update Mercurial version to run an automatic build in TeamCity.

Can I install a new version of Mercurial and configure TortoiseHg to use this new version without uninstalling my version of TortoiseHg?

(I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how old your TortoiseHG version is, you should be able to install the new Mercurial version on top of the one used by TortoiseHG.

Find where the `hg.exe` executable from TortoiseHG is (somewhere in the installation directory), make sur every instance of TortoiseHG is closed and then install the new Mercurial in the directory (or copy the new executable files)

However, I'm not sur this will works and you won't have access to the new functionnalities.

Can't you just install the new TortoiseHG and be done with it ?

Comment: TortoiseHg Installation comes with Mercurial? The installation of both should not come apart?

Comment: @AcazSouza Yes, TortoiseHG comes with Mercurial bundled. You can see the exact version of Mercurial for each specific TortoiseHG version on the main page : http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/

Comment: @krtek - `hg version` is faster and easier

Comment: It's definitely easier to just update TortoiseHG. I've updated through numerous versions of that and never had a problem.